# Django CSRF check failing with an Ajax GET request

Tags: javascript, jquery, django, ajax

I followed the instructions of this tutorial

https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/08/29/how-to-work-with-ajax-request-with-django.html

to check "User already exists or not" but Django still rejecting my POST request. I could use some help complying with Django's CSRF protection mechanism via my AJAX post. I've followed the directions here:

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/csrf/

But it didnt help me. It is my result in console:

```html
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block title %}
 Register
{% endblock %}
{% load crispy_forms_tags %}
{% block body %}
 <div class="container">
  <h1 class="text-center">Regiser</h1>
  <form class="form-group" method="POST" data-validate-username-url = "{% url 'validate_username' %}">
   {% csrf_token %}
   {{ form|crispy }}
   <input type="submit" name="Register" class="btn btn-primary text-center" value="Register">
  </form>
 </div>
{% endblock %}
{% block script %}
<script>
 function getCookie(name) {
     var cookieValue = null;
     if (document.cookie && document.cookie !== '') {
         var cookies = document.cookie.split(';');
         for (var i = 0; i < cookies.length; i++) {
             var cookie = cookies[i].trim();
             // Does this cookie string begin with the name we want?
             if (cookie.substring(0, name.length + 1) === (name + '=')) {
                 cookieValue = decodeURIComponent(cookie.substring(name.length + 1));
                 break;
             }
         }
     }
     return cookieValue;
 }

 function csrfSafeMethod(method) {
     // these HTTP methods do not require CSRF protection
     return (/^(GET|HEAD|OPTIONS|TRACE)$/.test(method));
 }

 $(document).ready(function() {
     var csrftoken = getCookie('csrftoken');
     $.ajaxSetup({
       beforeSend: function(xhr, settings) {
          if (!csrfSafeMethod(settings.type) && !this.crossDomain) {
             xhr.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
          }
        }
     });
 });

 $("#id_username").change(function() {
  var form = $(this).closest("form");
  $.ajax({
   url: form.attr('data-validate-username-url'),
   data: form.serialize(),
   dataType: 'json',
   success: data => {
    if (data.is_taken) {
     alert(data.error_message);
    }
   }
  });
 });

</script>
{% endblock %}
```

GET http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/validate_username?csrfmiddlewaretoken=kc6NtBw1pch0jjI0SGHhCVBeAKYWZrppOFgxHUaisCVqJUUlY73orIM3PDI0kejA&username=Tony&email=&password1=&password2= 500 (Internal Server Error)
send @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ (index):79
dispatch @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2
v.handle @ jquery-3.5.0.min.js:2

FieldError at /ajax/validate_username
Cannot resolve keyword 'username_iexact' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, orders, password, user_permissions, username
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/ajax/validate_username?csrfmiddlewaretoken=kc6NtBw1pch0jjI0SGHhCVBeAKYWZrppOFgxHUaisCVqJUUlY73orIM3PDI0kejA&username=Tony&email=&password1=&password2=

Django Version: 3.0.5
Exception Type: FieldError
Exception Value:
Cannot resolve keyword 'username_iexact' into field. Choices are: date_joined, email, first_name, groups, id, is_active, is_staff, is_superuser, last_login, last_name, logentry, orders, password, user_permissions, username
Exception Location: C:\Users\Le Dai Thang\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\sql\query.py in names_to_path, line 1483
Python Executable:  C:\Users\Le Dai Thang\Envs\myproject\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.7
Python Path:
['C:\Users\Le Dai Thang\Lecture7\project3',
 'C:\Users\Le Dai Thang\Envs\myproject\Scripts\python37.zip',
 'c:\users\le dai thang\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\DLLs',
 'c:\users\le dai thang\appdata\local\programs\python\python37\lib',
 'c:\users\le dai thang\appdata\local\programs\python\python37',
 'C:\Users\Le Dai Thang\Envs\myproject',
 'C:\Users\Le Dai Thang\Envs\myproject\lib\site-packages']

Comment: Why are you calling it "csft problem"? `Cannot resolve keyword 'username_iexact' into field` - you have single underscore here whereas double is required.

Comment: Thank you. It worked.

Comment: Because i didnt recognize